# javascript sleep on function which is not called

Tags: javascript, jira, velocity

I have this simple js in velocity jira template. I need
to sleep function and call function test but its not called at all.
Can you elaborate into this issue why its not happening? issueNumber
is velocity variable.

```js
    <script>
    function test() {
        var get = $issueNumber;
        alert(get);
    }
    setTimeout(test, 5000);
    test();
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi there. You are trying to call test twice. Are you saying that the immediate call succeeds and the delayed call doesn't?

Comment: I am not getting alert on screen. setTimeout is not only setting but also calling function?

Comment: I don't understand your response. setTimeout should call the function after 5000ms, it doesn't "set" anything. There is an answer below you can accept if it works. I don't know how Jira works, but setTimeout is going to change the execution context of "test". You can pass arguments to test() by giving them after the timeout delay value. If this helps I will re-post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call of `test`, the `test` function will be executed after 5 seconds as excepted.

```js
function test() {
   var get = 2;
   alert(get);
}
    
setTimeout(test, 5000);
```

Comment: There your issue is not related to javascript but to your environment or to your velocity configuration.